# How can I return object properties from list

Tags: c#

I have a class like:

```
public class EventsList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and list where I have collected some objects:

```
List<EventsList> CultureEvents { get; set; }
```

How can I make new string list with or get all of the objects Titles from list?

Comment: Loop on the list you have and insert each item.property to the list of strings.

Answer (score 5):

```
var result = CultureEvents.Select(x=>x.Title).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq; // this is usually at the top already

var result = from e in CultureEvents
             select e.Title
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<string> TitleList = new List<string>();
 foreach(var title in CultureEvents)
 {
     TitleList.Add(title.Title);
 }
```